# NumberPad on keyboard not responding for viewport selections

Tags: workflow

I can navigate in the view port: pan, rotate, side-to-side, up-down. With <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> pressed and using <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd>.

But <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>3</kbd>, <kbd>5</kbd>, <kbd>7</kbd> and <kbd>.</kbd> on the numpad do not change the view port when pressed.

I did find that *File > User Preferences > Input > Emulate Numpad* will activate the row of numeric characters. 1 through 0 from the left-hand side to be used as if I was on a laptop. I am using a desktop computer with a full keyboard. Is there a setting for this or am I missing something simple?
Using 1 - 0 above the alpha characters is working, but why is the numpad not working?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing the Num-Lock key at the top of the keyboard. Also if you have previously installed any key-mapping utilities on your computer this can screw with the number pad short cuts in Blender. It took me a long time to work out that an install of WMP Keys for Windows Media Player had messed up my default key mappings for Blender among other applications.

One other thought, open your User Preferences from the File menu and just make sure you don't have 'emulate num-pad' selected- that option maps the num-pad keys to the main number keys across the top of your keyboard instead.

Comment: Hello David, this is making me feel stupid but I do not know what / where to locate the Num-Lock key. To the right of F12 is Print Screen then, 2 sets of 3 keys for video control, below them 2 sets of 3 keys:scrolling insert delete home end, below them are the standard 4 arrow keys. To the right of them are the 0 to 9 period enter math function keys plus one for clear and a half moon key that put machine to sleep and a cap's lock indicator. I have no key(s) labeled Num-Lock it is a standard generic keyboard included with Dell machines. There is no FN key that would allow second functions

Comment: I added a screen shot of key board to original post, if you can add any additional info it would be great. This is incredibly stupid and I have no clue as what a Num-Lock key or where it would be on this key board. Thanks if you can help...Peace.....

Comment: I have not added any key-mapping utilities and this is the first time I have needed to use these keys. This area of the key board in the two years I have had this machine

Comment: No need to feel stupid, Dell keyboards are weird. To emulate the num-lock key on a dell keyboard press the 'FN' key,  and the 'F11' key at the same time. The 'Fn' key should be next to the 'Ctrl' key in the bottom left corner of your key board.

Comment: If that doesn't work, as a last resort you could pick up a cheap wireless keyboard to use with Blender instead- I have a Logitech wireless keyboard and mouse that I use with my laptop. It cost $30 from Kmart, has the num pad keys and works great with Blender. Before you do that though check the answer above again I added one more possible solution.

Comment: This key board does not have an FN key...in between Ctrl and Alt is the Windows flag key on the left on the right is Alt and a option key then Ctrl. Then option key is the equivalent of a right click on a web page offering cut, copy, paste and such.....

Answer (score 0):

Hello Dave and as I first stated I have to use the Emulate NUM-PAD setting from User Preferences in order to be able to navigate. With that setting enabled or not, my separate NUM PAD section of the full sized key board does not respond.

I consider this a work around for the issue even though it is not a limited laptop keyboard. That this setting enables if you DON'T have a NUM-PAD and is designed for. It just sucks to have an issue like this straight out of the box. It is probably not Blender but something with the key board I have. I am not buying a new one to see if it is the keys themselves. I was hoping it was just an internal Blender setting...

I have not gotten far enough into learning this to set my own key-short cuts but now these are off limits. Thanks for your time and thoughts, if I ever figure it out I post back. Don't think I will get an answer from anyone here.....bigger fish to fry then this one...Peace.....

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a bug on windows 10, multiple blender version mines is 2.93.5.
My first solution (I run blender in a sized window tutorial on another monitor using chrome) if you hit the maximize and restore it brings back the numpad. Or so I thought I had been doing that and so far it worked, as soon as I come to write this comment down it didn't. I suspect textbox controls on webpages steal numpad focus? Youtube would behave with the max/restore (still annoying to have to do) but this page wouldn't. Darts in the dark cause I have no idea why this would even happen in the first place.

Second solution that seems to work no matter what, is clicking the selectbox icon on the left in the viewport. That brought my numpad back no problems. Why you ask? I haven't a frigging clue man.

Third is to use the alt-middlemouse and drag in the direction the view is in. I guess this would be the most ideal solution but what happens if you're using a touchpad lol?(I actually own a Zbook with a middle button but my Legion only has 2).

Something seems to keep blender from getting focus back on the numpad for some reason. Other keyboard commands still work when bringing focus back via titlebar or alt-tab. At least in my particular case numlock (turning it off and on again) had no effect. Did a few more tests it seems that all the other buttons should do the trick, the tabs on top of the viewport also seem to work, this is very weird.